# Python subprocess wait keypress

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to run a program using the subprocess module. While running the program, there are cases where it waits for a button press to continue. It is not waiting for this input to the stdin input. The input sent to stdin is ignored by the program. Only when I press a button on the console will the program continue running.

I tried it like this:

```
proc = Popen("festival.exe level.sok", stdin=PIPE, text=True)
proc.stdin.write('.')
proc.stdin.flush()
```

It this case nothing happened.

and like this:

```
proc = Popen...
proc.communicate('.')
```

In this case, the python code will not continue running until I press a button on the console. If I set a timeout then the python code continues to run but festival.exe does not continue to run.

What should I do to make festival.exe continue running?

P.S.: festival.exe is a solver for sokoban. This case occurs when the given level cannot be solved. E.g.:

```
########  
#.. $ $#
#  @   #
########
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have the festival program like this:

```py
from random import getrandbits


solved = getrandbits(1)
if solved:
    print("executed correctly")
    
else:
    print('a error ocurred')
    input('press a button to continue') 
    exit(1)
```

you can solve with:

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


p = Popen(['python3','festival.py'],stdin=PIPE)
p.communicate(input=b'any\n')
```

Comment: No I'd like the subprocess(festival.exe) to continue running.

Comment: At one point, festival.exe is waiting for a button press, but it's not on stdin but on console somehow. This is the problem.

Comment: so, the festival.exe is waiting for a button press, independent of console?, and you dont want to terminate the program till subprocess end ?

Comment: If festival.exe can solve the level it doesn't wait for a button press, it just finishes running. Otherwise it write an error in stdout and doesn't finish running until I press a button, but this case stdout is blocked. As long as festival.exe is running, I don't know if it is solving the level or finding an unsolvable case.

Comment: lok if the answer solves your problem

Comment: The p.communicate() is blocked until i press a key on the console. So this code won't continue running by itself.

Comment: I don't want the user to press a button. I want festival.exe to finish running without pressing a button.

Comment: I think it can solve now,   try to run, if not, I dont know how to solves it

Comment: festival.exe is not a python code, so this does not solve the problem...

Comment: but I did this for example kkk ,in your case substitute the python3 festival.py, for the script will want to cal

Comment: Somehow festival.exe is not waiting for input to stdin... I tried this, but the code stops running at the communicate() line and doesn't move on until I press a button on the console.

Comment: I did an error, with the if, did you tried the last version?

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work... I went through all of these, tried communicate, writing to stdin, sending signals. None of these work in this case.